# Laravel - Accessing JSON give "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" error

Tags: json, laravel, shopify, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am handling a response from Shopify
I am getting the error when I access the image array from response
Here is the JSON object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7vjs.png)

This is the main code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUT9c.png)

Everything works fine except for **$row['image']['src']**
Wherever I use this, It gives me error

When I use dd, this the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPsTu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W08V0.png)

This is the error screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJme.jpg)

How do I solve it?

Comment: Please don't post [images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!